# Vim autoformat error

Tags: vim, autoformat

After I updated my vim plugins, I am having trouble with the vim autoformat plugin (https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat).

When I run :Autoformat, I get an error:

For html:

```
Definition in 'g:formatdef_htmlbeautify' was unsuccessful.
Definition in 'g:formatdef_tidy_html' was unsuccessful.
No format definitions were successful.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

For C/c++:

```
Definition in 'g:formatdef_clangformat' was unsuccessful.
Definition in 'g:formatdef_astyle_c' was unsuccessful.
No format definitions were successful.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have the formatters installed through the apt package manager, which means that according to the autoformat documentation, should mean that the plugin detects them automatically.

I have tried reinstalling the plugin, it did not help.

Comment: Use the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat/issues).

Answer (score 0):

`vim-autoformat` detects plugins automatically if they are installed properly.
In the case where you don't want to get errors on display and 'Press ENTER or type command to continue' just type `:silent Autoformat`.

Comment: Silencing does not help. It is not formatting my code - it just gives the error message I described. The formatters are installed through the apt package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this week on a Debian machine.

After deleting the vim-autoformat folder from `~/.vim/bundles` (installed with Vundle) and installing it again (`:PluginInstall`) everything worked as expected again.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it for me. Strange though that reinstalling did not fix it when the problem first occurred.